# Capitalization of the first letters of words in a sentence using python code

Tags: python, regex, string

The code below capitalizes the first word of the words in "w".I would like to know how the function captilize(sentence) works? Specifically what does sentence.split do?

`

```
import random

def test():
  w = ["dog", "cat", "cow", "sheep", "moose", "bear", "mouse", "fox", "elephant",    "rhino", "python"]
  s = ""

  #random.seed(rnd_seed)

  for i in range(0, random.randint(10,15)):
    s += random.choice(w) + " "
  print "<ignore>Sentence: " + s
  print "Capitalized: " + capitalize(s).strip()


def capitalize(sentence):
  w = sentence.split()
  ww = ""
  for word in w:
    ww += word.capitalize() + " "
  return ww


test()`
```

Comment: At an interactive python prompt, try `help(''.split)`

Comment: You will never learn if you do not try. This question must be closed because it does not show a minimum understanding of the code.

Comment: As @Anonymous said, do something on your own, like trying help commands in your python prompt.

Comment: Play around with the code and you'll be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.split(sep):**
Specifically split method takes a string and returns a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If no separator value is passed, it takes whitespace as the separator.

For example:

```
a = "This is an example"
a.split()        # gives ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']  -> same as a.split(' ')
```

Talking about your function, it takes a sentence in the form of a string and returns the sentence with each word capitalized. Lets see it line by line:

```
def capitalize(sentence):    # sentence is a string
  w = sentence.split()       # splits sentence into words eg. "hi there" to ['hi', there']
  ww = ""                   # initializes new string to empty
  for word in w:                 # loops over the list w
    ww += word.capitalize() + " "      # and capitalizes each word and adds to new list ww
  return ww                               # returns the new list
```